# How to incorporate the SQL Server Express installer in my own setup?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, setup-deployment

I want to publish an application which has these requirements:

- .NET Framework
- SQL Server 2005 Express

I'm using the 'Setup Project' in Visual Studio 2008. I have added my project files and it has  successfully detected the .NET Framework dependency.

The problem is:

- I want to include all the files (.NET Framework and SQL Server Express setup files) with the installer.
- I want the installer to first check and see if the required files are installed on the target computer.
- I want to add SQL Server Express installer to the dependencies so that the installer sets up .NET Framework and SQL Server Express automatically on the target computer if needed.

Comment: Fix your title to be something more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this one: [Include another MSI file in my setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283890/include-another-msi-file-in-my-setup-project)