# Append setup files in exe and extract while executing

Tags: c#, installation, merge

I want to write a C# application, which will append setup files (these files are not pre-requisites) in it and then build it. The setup files which will be appended are different setup files. I cant give all these to client and so i need to merge them into 1 and execute individually as per client requirement.

Now when I execute this C# application, I want those setup files to be extracted to some location(C:\Windows\Temp).

I will be happy if after extracting the files, setup file gets triggered and executes.

Comment: what do you mean by append setup files, **what** should it append?

Comment: Are you the author behind all the three setups you want to merge? Are these setup files truly a *setup* or simply an x-copy of involved files. Do you want to execute the three setups as a chain of events or do you want to extract the relevant files from each setup (ignoring any GUI steps)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a thread about chaining setups:

[Include another MSI file in my setup project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283890/include-another-msi-file-in-my-setup-project)

<strike>Do you want to install prerequisites for your own application?</strike>

If so, then this link should help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx

This is the key paragraph:

*"Each prerequisite is a bootstrapper package. A bootstrapper package is a group of directories and files that contain manifest files that describe how the prerequisite should be installed. If your application prerequisites are not listed in the Prerequisite Dialog Box, you can create custom bootstrapper packages and add them to Visual Studio. Then you can select the prerequisites in the Prerequisites Dialog Box. For more information, see Creating Bootstrapper Packages."*

Comment: No Simen, I have 3 setup files and i want to merge all of them and trigger 1 setup.